# Nullpointerexception when reload listview

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have a `listview` using `simpleAdapter` and an `AsyncTask` that I call fragment A. In `doInBackground` I get data from a json then in `onPostExecute` I set data into adapter.

The first time I call A everything run well. From A I move to B then back to A it's run well too. But when I try to start A from A it's show an error Nullpointerexception at line code below:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
               // Updating listview
               getActivity(), arrMeetings,
               R.layout.meeting_item, new String[] {mtTAG_MEETINGNAME, mtTAG_DATE, mtTAG_TIME, mtTAG_LOCATION, mtTAG_MEETINGSTATUS},
               new int[] {  R.id.txtTitleMeeting, R.id.txtDatetime, R.id.txtTime, R.id.txtLocation, R.id.txtStatusMeeting});
```

Any idea?

The logcat show:

```
05-15 10:52:15.863: W/dalvikvm(1294): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3acaba8)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 1294
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at info.android.mh.fragment.Tabview_Accepted_Meeting_Fragment$GetAcceptedMeetings$2.<init>(Tabview_Accepted_Meeting_Fragment.java:193)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at info.android.mh.fragment.Tabview_Accepted_Meeting_Fragment$GetAcceptedMeetings.onPostExecute(Tabview_Accepted_Meeting_Fragment.java:197)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at info.android.mh.fragment.Tabview_Accepted_Meeting_Fragment$GetAcceptedMeetings.onPostExecute(Tabview_Accepted_Meeting_Fragment.java:1)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 10:52:15.893: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Update code

doInBackground:

```
    List<NameValuePair> meetingparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    meetingparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attendant[user_id]", Userid));
    // Getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject meetingjson = jParser.makeHttpRequest(str_url_getmeeting, "POST", meetingparams);                

    Log.d("user's meeting: ", meetingjson.toString());
    try {
        if(meetingjson.getInt("msg")==1){
            JSONArray meetings = meetingjson.getJSONArray("meeting");
            arrMeetings.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < meetings.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = meetings.getJSONObject(i);                           
                String strRole = c.getString("role_id");
                if(strRole.equals("1")){
                    String strId = c.getString(mtTAG_MEETINGID);
                    String strName = c.getString(mtTAG_MEETINGNAME);
                    String strContent = c.getString(mtTAG_CONTENT);
                    String[] strDateTime = c.getString(mtTAG_DATE).split("T");
                    String strDuration = c.getString(mtTAG_DURATION);
                    String strLocation = c.getString(mtTAG_LOCATION);                               
                    String strCoordinate = c.getString(mtTAG_COORDINATE);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(mtTAG_MEETINGID, strId);
                    map.put(mtTAG_MEETINGNAME, strName);
                    map.put(mtTAG_CONTENT, strContent);
                    map.put(mtTAG_DATE, strDateTime[0]);
                    map.put(mtTAG_TIME, strDateTime[1].substring(0, strDateTime[1].length()-5));
                    map.put(mtTAG_DURATION, strDuration);
                    map.put(mtTAG_LOCATION, strLocation);                               
                    map.put(mtTAG_COORDINATE, strCoordinate);

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String formattedDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
                    Date inputDate = df.parse(strDateTime[0]);
                    Log.d("Date", inputDate.toString());
                    Date currentDate = df.parse(formattedDate);
                    String status="";

                    if(inputDate.compareTo(currentDate)==0)
                        status = "Today";
                    else if(inputDate.compareTo(currentDate)<0)
                        status = "Done";
                    else if(inputDate.compareTo(currentDate)>0)
                        status = "Incoming";

                    map.put(mtTAG_MEETINGSTATUS, status);

                    arrMeetings.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("arrMeetings: ", arrMeetings.toString());                 
                }                           
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            return null;
```

onPostExucute

```
mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
         // Updating listview
            getActivity(), arrMeetings,
                R.layout.meeting_item, new String[] {mtTAG_MEETINGNAME, mtTAG_DATE, mtTAG_TIME, mtTAG_LOCATION, mtTAG_MEETINGSTATUS},
                new int[] {  R.id.txtTitleMeeting, R.id.txtDatetime, R.id.txtTime, R.id.txtLocation, R.id.txtStatusMeeting})};
```

acceptedLv.setAdapter(adapter);

Then I call `AsyncTask` from `onResume`

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: getActivity() returns null

Comment: what is line 85 @ `SimpleAdapter`?

Comment: Please share the relevant methods, your full AsyncTask, marking which lines are #193, #197.

Comment: Line #193 is `adapter = new SimpleAdapter`